# How to 301 redirect from example.com/word.html or word-abc.html or abc-word.html to example.com

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

how to 301 redirect from example.com/word.html or word-abc.html or abc-word.html or url that contain "word" to example.com

Now I just do it manually with this simple code :

```
Redirect 301 /word.html example.com
Redirect 301 /word-abc.html example.com
Redirect 301 /abc-word.html example.com
```

I want do it automatically redirect from url that contain "word" to example.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `RedirectMatch` directive for its regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 \bword\b http://example.com
```

This will redirect any UR that has `word` (with word boundaries) to `http://example.com`

Comment: Hi @anubhava thanks for your code. its really working.
hmm.. its possible if i want to redirect by Random Uppercase?
e.g : Word-aBc-woRd-ABC.html to example.com?

Comment: Hmm that is strange requirement. Does that mean redirect only when if there are mixed case letters in a URI?

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 [A-Z] http://example.com` might do it? That'll just work if there are ANY caps in the url at all.

Comment: Hmm interesting. If you don't mind please create a new request with that requirement since that is *very different* from this answer. Meanwhile I will try to find an answer for that.

Comment: @r3mus: No `[A-Z]` won't work because OP wants mixed case so it should allow `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` both

Comment: Heh, yeah. Except that would match all lowercase too.